# Error getting data attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-data-attribute

I have a node that I assigned a data attribute `data-myid = "id3"`. When I try to print the value of this attribute I don't get `id3` but `null` or `undefined`.

This is the code:

```
console.log("node2");
console.log(node2);
console.log("node2.getAttribute(\"data-myid\") = " + node2.getAttribute("data-myid"));
console.log("node2.getAttribute(\"myid\") = " + node2.getAttribute("myid"));
console.log("node2.dataset.myid = " + node2.dataset.myid);
```

I tried different ways and yet the prints I get are:

[image]

Why? How can I get the value of the `myid`?
Thanks a lot!

PS: Why use a `data attribute` instead of `id` depends on my application. So I will not change `myid` with `id`.

Also I would *only* use *JavaScript*, not jQuery.

*JSFiddle*: 
I never used JSFiddle and I do not know how it works. I did this https://jsfiddle.net/xy1jxeos/ but not exactly what my code, here is simplified

---

OK there is something wrong. I created this simple file to see if the problem was elsewhere:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>get attribute</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="main" data-myid="id3"></div>

    <script>
        console.log(document.getElementById("main"));
        console.log(document.getElementById("main").getAttribute("myid"));
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the problem is still there! Here are the prints:

```
<div id="main" data-myid="id3"></div>
null
```

How is it possible? Where am I wrong?

Comment: I add the attribute using Javascript in this way: `node.childNodes[i].dataset.myid = att.myID;`. Making prints working properly, the attributes are assigned.

Comment: Show how you declare and assign `node2`. Also, can you reproduce this problem in SO snippet or JSFiddle?

Comment: which browser is this (looks like chrome)

Comment: there is nothing obviously wrong with the code in the question, or how you set that attribute - a "minimal" example of code (code snippet here or fiddle or whatever) that exhibits the same problem would definitely help in tracking down the problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I modified the main message..

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes it's chrome

Answer (score -1):

It seems something is wrong with your `node2`
Please provide how you assigned it. Check this code [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hdrdnkp8/)

```
var node2 = document.getElementById(element).children[0];
```

If you did like this, then it's ok.